# How to obfuscate ES6 class method names using Webpack/Babel/UglifyJS

Tags: javascript, webpack, obfuscation, babeljs, uglifyjs

I have ES7 code that I am compiling to ES5 (using Webpack/Babel/UglifyJS). I want to obfuscate the code as much as possible.

Babel uses a key/value object for classes, which preserves the name of the functions:

[image]

Is there a tool that obfuscates ES6 class names and methods?

I am looking for this transformation:

`ES6 -> Obfuscated ES6 (esp classes)`

My code is compiled to a single bundle, and the classes are not used externally outside of the bundle.

Current tools I am aware of:

- Babili (does not do this).
- UglifyJS (takes ES5 as input).

Comment: What Babel presets have you used? And what version of Babel?

Comment: 1. why? its not supported by some browsers. Why do you prefer obfuscated instead of working code?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com) and know they provide obfuscation for classes, methods, and variables. You have to pay to use it, but your code won't have a timeout after protecting it, and they offer support as well if you need help using their program.